# Update all rows in a selected row where time colume has time less than current time by 3 days using mysqli php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table of users in my database with time column set to default timestamp and status column have value of either `0` or `1`.

I already selected the rows where `username='$username' and status= '1'`.

Now I want to loop through these selected rows and check for rows where time in the time column is less than current time (i.e time()) by at least 7 days and then update the status column of such rows, setting `status=2`.

I've read a lot of things online but couldn't get to do this... Below is my current code, I'm using mysqli.

```
$sql= mysqli_query($conn, 
          "select from tables where username=$username and status='1' ") ;

$row=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You don’t need to loop through it, because you can specify where condition inside your update statement:

```
    $sql= mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tables SET status = '2' WHERE username = '$username' AND status = '1' AND time <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY") ;

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ;
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrii Filenko, but here is the error message I got when I run your code: Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp1\htdocs\me\test.php on line 16

Comment: @Benito might be caused because username was unquoted, updated the answer, don't forget to change 'tables' to your real table

Answer (score -1):

I just did a work around my question above and is working perfectly ok for me now. This is what I did:

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from table_name");

while($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$day= abs(time ()-$time)/86400;
$ql= mysqli_query($conn, "update table_name set status='2' where name='$username' and status='1' and $day>4"); 
//for 4 days interval
}
```